# How do soit's 3 significations semantically appertain each other [1] 3SG PRS subjunctive of être, [2] "let be" in math, and [3] "either ... or"?

Tags: étymologie

What's the semantic field of [*soit*](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/soit)? What notions underlie these 3 significations that look completely unrelated  to me?

> [image]

Alain Rey, ed. *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, 4th edn. 2 vols. Paris: Le Robert, 2016 (1st edn. 1992). Anyone know the page number?

My local library has merely 2 of the [French etymological dictionaries listed on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_dictionary#Print). "soit" was overlooked in  Jacqueline Picoche [fr]. *Dictionnaire étymologique du français*. Paris: Le Robert, 1971.

I used [interlinear glossing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_glossing_abbreviations) in the title. 3SG PRS = 3rd person singular present.

Answer (score 6):

They are all related to the verb ***être*** and can eventually be translated to "**be**".

1. *Qu'il **soit** coupable ou pas, je m'en fiche.*
   → Whether he **is** guilty or not, I don't care.
   → **Be** he guilty or not [...].
2. *Je partirai **soit** lundi, **soit** mardi* (I will leave either Monday or Tuesday.) means under the cover *Je viendrai **que ce soit** lundi, **que ce soit** mardi*.
   → I will leave whether it **is** Monday, whether it **is** Tuesday
   → **Be** it Monday, **be** it Tuesday
3. ***Soit** c la vitesse de la lumière dans le vide, ...* : means *Admettons que c **soit** la vitesse de la lumière dans le vide*
   → Let's posit that c **is** the speed of light in a vacuum, ...
   → Let c **be** the speed of light, ...

Answer (score -3):

Le **champ lexical** (*semantic field*) du mot *soit* est le verbe *être.*

> Les mots d'un même champ lexical peuvent être des noms, des adjectifs
> qualificatifs ou **des verbes.**

[champ lexical, or semantic field in English](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champ_lexical)

> [champ lexical](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-10386.php)

The three meanings in French are derived from the third person singular present subjunctive of the verbe être.

- the either /or use: soit x, soit y can be literally translated as "**be**" as in "be it this or be it that", which in English is usually rendered as either this or that.
- the use in math, it "let x **be**".
- the use of soit at the end of a phrase as an explanation, which is translated as: that is, which is the same as "c'est à dire" or "à savoir", as cited in the question: Alain Rey, ed. *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, 4th edn. 2 vols. Paris: Le Robert, 2016. That source cites the three uses explained in this answer.

Comment: @EylaChu-Generis No matter what I say or how I say it, there are those determined to downvote. The main point of my answer was not translation.